# How to continuously send images from raspberry to pc without delay?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send webcam captured images from pi to pc, but while using socket programming for it, i'm getting a significant amount of delay (about 5-6 seconds per image). Am I doing something wrong over here? Is there a way to reduce this delay or any other better technique to send the data to pc with minimum delay?

Server side:

```
import socket                   

port = 60000                    
s = socket.socket()            
host = ""     
s.bind((host, port))            
s.listen(5)                     

print('Server listening....')

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    filename='mytext.txt'
    f = open(filename,'rb')
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       conn.send(l)
       print('Sent ',repr(l))
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.send('Thank you for connecting')
    conn.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket                   # Import socket module
import time

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = "192.1.1.1"              #Ip address that the TCPServer  is there


port = 60000                    # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!")


with open('received_file.png', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        # print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        # print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)
    print(time.time() - start)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Comment: You should use the `with` statement at the server too. And at the client, you don't need to close the file when its opened inside the `with`. https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: Sending 1 KB at a time is going to be slow. If you are doing this for practice, I recommend looking at various protocols like FTP. If you are doing this actually for doing it, I recommend using some library that transfers a file more optimally.

Comment: The socket module has the `sendfile()` method which should be close to optimal for non-Windows platforms. On the receiving (client) side, use a larger buffer, say 16k, for the `recv()`.

Comment: Note that your code includes the time to read the file from disk...

Comment: Are you using a wired or wifi connection? I have found I can get nearly twice the bandwidth of the built-in wired Ethernet if I use a USB-attached Gbit Ethernet adaptor.